# Use PostFix on Ubuntu 16.04 with Outlook, Works?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

Folks, I want my own email address, from my domain. I think installing PostFix, and then connecting Outlook to it, I get a way to get it, and respond to emails locally. That's true? I use Ubuntu 16.04. I need a way !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do it. If you don't need to send email trough internet, you can configure postfix to send email only for your local domain.
Besides Postfix (MTA) you have to install a MDA, like [dovecot](https://www.dovecot.org/).